# No auto foco cuando inicio actividad

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de iniciar una actividad sin foco en el `EditText` para que este tenga un `background` diferente. Es decir, quiero que se inicie la actividad sin que haga foco en el `EditText` para que se vea gris y que cuando se presione en el `EditText` para escribir que este se ponga en blanco. He hecho dos shapes para distinguir el foco.

Con foco:

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ff000000"/>

    <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>

    <corners android:radius="500px"/>
</shape>
```

Sin foco:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#AFAFAF"/>

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ff000000"/>

    <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>

    <corners android:radius="500px"/>
</shape>
```

Esta es el `layout` de la actividad donde está el `EditText`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.TrantorActivity"
    android:background="@color/negro">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearBuscar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
            <EditText
                android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                android:textColorHint="@color/blanco"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/etBuscar"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                android:id="@+id/btnBusqueda"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_search"/>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="591dp">
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="591dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

El problema es que siempre que abro esta actividad, me hace el foco en el `EditText` por lo que siempre está con el `background` con foco. Así lo valido para cambiar el **background**:

```
if(textoBusqueda.requestFocus()){
            textoBusqueda.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.trantor_confoco);
        }else{
            textoBusqueda.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.trantor_sinfoco);
        }
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Lo que quiero es que si el `EditText` no tiene el foco, muetre un shape y si tiene el foco muestre el otro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para forzar al edittext  que no tenga el foco, es con la función clearFocus(), por ejemplo:

```
miEdit.clearFocus()
```

Pero la verdad es que tienes un fallo....  el problema es que colocas este codigo:

```
if(textoBusqueda.requestFocus()){
            textoBusqueda.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.trantor_confoco);
        }else{
            textoBusqueda.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.trantor_sinfoco);
        }
```

con la funcion requestFocus(), le estas asignando el foco al edittext

este codigo deberias colocarlo en un listener de tipo onfocuschange

```
textoBusqueda.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if(hasFocus==true){
             v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.trantor_confoco);
            }else{
             v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.trantor_sinfoco);
            }


          }
        });
```